# regex for valid ftp file path

Tags: asp.net, regex, url, path

I am looking for validating a textbox in my asp.net application for a valid file path like

1. \\127.0.0.1\folder
2. http://ftp.google.com
   and all other valid file paths

Comment: can you give an example of an invalid path ? I think you can use pretty much any string as valid path (relative, absolute, etc.)

Comment: I would even say, more examples of both valid and invalid paths? Is, for example, `ftp+ssh://a.com.:8441/dir/file.txt` a valid path? (with absolute domain name) Are non-punnycode-translated internationalized domain names allowed? Non-escaped non-ascii characters? what protocols? etc.

Comment: Invalid path is like : "abcd" or any other string that is not a valid FTP

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it can be solved using Regex, but too complex for such a task, and it is slow. In my opinion, the best solution for your problem is not regex. You can easily validate file path by utilizing built-in ASP string functions, such as InStr, Left, Right, Mid, Len, etc.

**Good Resource to Read:**

- [ASP String Function List](http://www.aspisfun.com/functions/string/)
- [String Handling functions in ASP](http://www.plus2net.com/asp-tutorial/string-functions.php)